# GNOME can’t be launched

Tags: fedora, gnome

After reboot of my Fedora Linux I was met with a white screen that said “System could not restore”. I launched console, using Ctrl+Alt+F2, then tried to use startx, gnome-session, gnome-shell. Startx apparently started X server, but I still can’t figure out how to get GUI up and running. Gnome-session responded with nothing, gnome-shell responded with “Unsupported session type”. How do I launch my GNOME?

**EDIT**

I deleted my nVidia drivers, then rebooted my PC and everything worked. Now I can't figure out is there any way to install nvidia drivers the way they won't lay GNOME down.